# How to stop a jar file from running from a jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, web-applications, jar, processing

I have created an web application that trigers some .jar applets.
I print the jars with the HTML  tags through a servlet in a jsp.

Imagine two situations. A anb B.
Starting with A the jar runs.
I go to B, the 2nd jar replaces the first.
When I return to A, the 2nd jar is removed but the first jar fails to start with a *Adding same VBO twice + null pointer exception.*

So I believe I have to stop it after leaving situation A.
**Is there a way to stop the .jar from running from inside the servlet?**

Thanks in advance.

**Added stacktrace:**

> Adding same VBO twice. Exception in thread "Animation Thread" P3D:
>   Already called beginDraw(). javax.media.opengl.GLException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.jav‌​a:98)
>   at
>   jogamp.opengl.ThreadingImpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(ThreadingImpl.java:196)
>   at
>   javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:164)
>   at
>   javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.maybeDoSingleThreadedWorkaround(GLCanvas.java:83‌​1)

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception, and the code causing this exception to be thrown. Trying random things is not the best way to sove a problem. The best way is to analyze the cause of the problem.

Comment: The exception I get when I return from B to A is:

**Adding same VBO twice 
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" P3D: Already called beginDraw(). 
javax.media.opengl.GLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at  jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.java:98)
 at  jogamp.opengl.ThreadingImpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(ThreadingImpl.java:196)
 at  javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:164)
 at  javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.maybeDoSingleThreadedWorkaround(GLCanvas.java:831)...**

and goes on with much more.

Comment: This does not seem to have anything to do with the "Processing" programming language... wrong tag?

Comment: Yes it does, since the .jar files are processing sketches.

Comment: from the stack trace, it looks like the opengl context is already in use. Are both sketches trying to claim the opengl pipeline?

Comment: Yes, they are two different sketches trying to claim the same opengl lib.

Comment: It's a good bet that the "and B replaces A" does not actually unload the sketch. Does A at any point when it's being swapped out call exit(), to release all the locks and resource pointers?

Comment: Yes that is what I believe also. However I don't know how to close the applet from the jsp or the servlet since it was called with a js <script> code.