# How to stop the process from running?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, executable-jar

This question might be a bit similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15173904/9656249) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17164898/9656249) question.

How do I stop a *particular* .jar file from running in Mac OS?  When I open up the activity monitor, it does not show the process listed.  But I am sure it is running because when I visit the localhost (I have developed a .jar from a Spring Boot application), I can still see the welcome message!

Could you please let me know how I could stop a particular .jar file from executing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jps` to get the pid (and jar name), `awk` to parse the pid and then `kill` it. Like, (with bash or similar)

```
kill -9 $(jps | grep -i "thejar.jar" | awk '{print $1}')
```

or

```
kill -9 `jps | grep -i "thejar.jar" | awk '{print $1}'`
```

The `-i` option to `grep` makes it case insensitive. Omit if that is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: `ps -aux | grep xxx`, xxx is the name of `.jar`

Step2: `kill -9 pid`, pid you can get from the first command.